# GPGPU programming architecture for HSA in C++ for Matrix Math

Tags: c++, matrix, gpgpu, lapack, blas

GPU Compute Programmers,

I have a C++ program which currently relies on the ACML (LAPACK) to invert and multiple fairly large matrices of single precision fp values (E.g. 4,000 x 4,000).  These matrices are very sparse although they do not always fit nicely into a diagonal matrix so I cannot presently reduce them.  The other thing about this program is I have to do this invert and multiply several times (serially) as part of a Newton Rapson.  However, I have several thousand permutations which can be done in parallel, each with a small change to the matrix before again calculating and inverting the Jacobian.  This is all single precision fp, and seems perfectly suited for the GPU.  My question is this...

I suspect I will need to use the AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing Math Libraries (APPML) for OpenGL as that is the only thing (non-CUDA, I want to be GPU agnostic) I know of which is available with BLAS functionality.  My problem is I do not see the LAPACK dgetrf and dgetri functions included in APPML (yes, these are fp64 but I don't need that precision).  Would C++ AMP be a better alternative?  I am very interested in HSA features of passing pointers rather than copying data as there is a lot of data in flight here and some calculations still are done on the CPU.  I believe that copy overhead would kill me otherwise.  Ultimately, performance is the key and I want to make the right architectural decisions to set myself up for the most performance I can wring out of HSA GPUs coming out over the next 6 months.

I am using VS 2013 Ultimate preview and would be able to take advantage of C++ AMP for these HSA capabilities.  I just want to make sure I am making the right long term architectural decision now while my program is in its infancy.  Here is a link and snippet from some interesting data I found on Anandtech:

http://anandtech.com/show/7118/windows-81-and-vs2013-bring-gpu-computing-updates-to-direct3d-and-c-amp-

*C++ AMP, Microsoft's C++ extension for GPU computing, has also been updated with the upcoming VS2013. I think the biggest feature update is that C++ AMP programs will also gain a shared memory feature on APUs/SoCs where the compiler and runtime will be able to eliminate extra data copies between CPU and GPU. This feature will also be available only on Windows 8.1 and it is likely built on top of the "map default buffer" as Microsoft's AMP implementation uses Direct3D under the hood. C++ AMP also brings some other nice additions including enhanced texture support and better debugging abilities.*

Any thoughts, additional questions or discussion would be greatly appreciated!